# How is bot.login(token); an unexpected end of input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am new to coding in Discord.js and everything has been working PERFECTLY in my Index.js code for a few days.  I don't know what changed, but it says "Unexpected end of input" and refers to the line with the bot token.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

bot.on('message', message => {  

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!bot.commands.has(command)) return;

try {
    bot.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command.');
};
});

bot.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {

    try {  

    var facts = [
    "Press F to pay respects to **" + `${member.user.tag}` + "**.",
    "**" + `${member.user.tag}` + "** has ascended.",
    "The wild **" + `${member.user.tag}` + "** used teleport.",
    "Why did you set me on fire, **" + `${member.user.tag}` +"**? Why didn't you just write your essay?",
    "**" + `${member.user.tag}` + ":** Gone but not forgotten.",
    "**" + `${member.user.tag}` + "** has decided to leave the server...Effective immediately.",
    "Ouch, **" + `${member.user.tag}` + "** let the door hit them on the way out.",
    "Farewell, **" + `${member.user.tag} + "**."];

    var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);

    bot.channels.get("643551580465004583").send(facts[fact]);
    } catch(e){
        console.log("[ERROR]",e)}
});

bot.login(token);
```

It says the error is the line that contains `bot.login(token);` and I don't see any brackets missing partners. Please help!

I have to write some more text so that my question does not contain more code than text but I feel like it's relatively self-explanatory at this point, honestly. How much more are you going to make me write?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing backtick here:

```
"Farewell, **" + `${member.user.tag} + "**."];
```

It should be:

```
"Farewell, **" + `${member.user.tag}` + "**."];
```

---

Also, please read up on [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as you're making your string concatenation a lot more complex than its need to be. :P